# Evento de botón dinámico para Android generado en Xamarin

Tags: android, xamarin

quería consulta si alguien sabe como puedo llamar el evento de un botón creado dinámicamente en Android con Xamarin, Yo creo el botón de esta manera

```
                ImageButton btn = new ImageButton(this);
                btn.LayoutParameters = lp;
                btn.Id.ToString("txt"+i.ToString());
                btn.LayoutParameters.Height = 80;
                btn.LayoutParameters.Width = 85;
                panelBotones.AddView(btn);
```

Ahora mi duda es como llamo el evento del botón (cualquiera que presione),  con este ID generado automáticamente btn.Id.ToString("txt"+i.ToString());

Ya intente con
Button prueba = (Button)FindViewById(Resource.Id. aquí no se como llamarlo ya que no se como capturar el evento de ese botón creado dinamicamente)// ;

Muchas gracias de antemano!